# Using VBA in excel to set specific formatting when creating new sheets using modules

Tags: vba, excel

My project is to create an easy to use list based off of a master list of items that are separated into separate sheets according to shop, and then format them ready for printing.

Currently, I have a macro button that divides up a master list into separate sheets depending on what value is in the shop column.

Next, I need to copy the formatting or set up the formatting of the new sheets in a very specific way: Print breaks to the right of column J, landscape, a specific header, and a box of text at the very bottom with space for a signature.

So far I've only managed to set the new sheets to landscape. Page break doesn't work.

```
Sub SetAttributes()

For Each xWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
xWorksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
xWorksheet.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
xWorksheet.Columns("K").PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

Next xWorksheet

End Sub
```

Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I can move forward?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while prepping the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing the specific formatting rather than code that simply copies the formatting.

```
Sub SetAttributes()

    'Code telling excel that I want the following to apply to all my
    'sheets in this workbook
    For Each xWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Set the page as landscape
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape


    xWorksheet.Columns("K").PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual


'Set space for the header by increasing TOP margin
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = _
     Application.InchesToPoints(1.5)


'Inclusion Logo
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = ThisWorkbook.Path + 
    "\Logo2.png"


    'SSSFT logo
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&G"
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture.Filename = ThisWorkbook.Path + 
    "\Logo1.png"

    ' Address
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&G"
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.CenterHeaderPicture.Filename = ThisWorkbook.Path + 
    "\Address.png"

    'Footer
    xWorksheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&A"

    'set column width to help printing format
    xWorksheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 10
    xWorksheet.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 21
    xWorksheet.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 26
    xWorksheet.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 9

    'Insert space for signatures 3 rows below the last row of
    'data with a space for the pharmacy to date and sign

      'Dim lastRow As Long

        lastRow = xWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    ' wrap text
    xWorksheet.Range("A:J").WrapText = True


'And move to the next sheet
Next xWorksheet

End Sub
```